# Как получить все href из таблицы?

Tags: javascript

```html
<table class='table'><tr><td><a href="url">bla</a></td></tr><tr><a href="url2">bla2</a>


</tr></table>
```

Без jQuery нужно получить все ссылки из href

Comment: Укажите пример таблицы, чтобы понять, где конкретно находятся ссылки.

Comment: <pre><table><tr><td><div class='one'><div class='two'><a href="url">bla</a></div></div></td></tr></table>  </pre> и  конечно строк оч много

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const hrefs = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('table.table a[href]'),
  element => element.href
);

console.log(hrefs);
```

```html
<table class='table'>
  <tr><td><a href="http://example.com/">bla</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="http://example.com/">bla2</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Наверное не пойдет. 
Мне нужно в цикле словить ссылку, распарсить её, и ели все хорошо, то после </tr> добавить еще одно <tr>  с дополнительными данными.

Пишу расширение для хрома, сам пхпшник).

Comment: Тогда вам нужно подробнее описать эти дополнительные условия в вопросе.

Comment: var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  //alert(links[i].href);
  
  let parent = links[i].closest('td');
  
  //как узнать тут родительскую tr ? 
   console.log(parent);
}

Comment: Ситуация такая. Есть таблица.  Во второй строке есть href= по которому я понимаю что добрался до нужного места. Ибо идентификарто спрятан в урле 

И после </tr> нужно вставить еще одну <tr> с доп данными...

Comment: Я щас отдельный пост сделаю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146619/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-table-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-tr-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9