# Поиск по table и вставка новой tr после найденной

Tags: javascript

Сам пхпшник.С фронтом почти не работал. Задача: пишу расширение для Хрома. Со всем справился, кроме одного. В Storage у меня хранится JSON мне нужно найти совпадение ключа с path от урла, который внутри таблицы в href.   И после того как я нашел, я должен нарисовать  еще один ...... после найденного tr.

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="url/path">blabla"></a></td><td> ... </td>  ... много </tr>
<tr><td><a href="url/path">blabla"></a></td><td> ... </td>  ... много </tr>
</table>
```

Получить ссылки получилось. Но не пойму как получить родителя tr чтобы после него сделать вставку. Без jQuery, ибо с ним я умею.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  //alert(links[i].href);
  
  let parent = links[i].closest('td');
  
  //как узнать тут родительскую tr ? 
   console.log(parent);
}
```

Comment: `links[i].closest('td').closest('tr')`? Или просто `links[i].closest('tr')`?

Comment: Да! Второй вариант, блин как же я протупил. А подскажите - как вставить теперь новую TR, ибо innerHTML после closest пишет  Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Написал в ответе, заодно предложил упрощение цикла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(const link of links){
  let parent = link.closest('tr');
  const newTr = document.createElement('tr');
  parent.after(newTr);
  const newTd = document.createElement('td');
  newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  newTd.textContent = 'New content.';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="url/path">blabla</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="url/path">blabla</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! А не могли бы вы в двух словах рассказать cons let и var.  Я еще помню ковырял js когда только var был.  Почему именно в цикле const  ? :)

Comment: `var` сейчас используется реже, потому что область видимости у такой переменной — целая функция (или глобальная область), а у `let` и `const` область более узкая, функция или блок. Обычно `let` используют тогда, когда привязка переменной меняется (например, счётчик в цикле), а `const` — когда не меняется (хотя значение, к которому привязана переменная, может меняться, например содержимое массива). В данном случае каждая итерация цикла создаёт отдельную область видимости, в которой привязка `link` не меняется, поэтому можно использовать`const`.

Comment: Супер! Огромное спасибо!  Простое объяснение!